# Timeline con iconos de fechas

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, scss

Buen día. 
Tengo la siguiente linea del tiempo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría que la barra de los iconos con las fechas aparezca arriba en vez de en la parte de abajo, ya revise el HTML y el CSS pero no me permite poder subirlos.
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Saludos.

ingreso link: https://codepen.io/eltonmesquita/pen/DcHup

Donde se encuentra el cógido ya que no me permite subirlo por este medio.

Comment: Puedes insertar código dentro del post que ponga por una parte el HTML y por otra el CSS?

Comment: Porfavor comparte tu código

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es la barra de navegación arriba en vez de abajo... Solo tienes que cambiar la propiedad de ```.tl-nav-wrapper``` la parte de ```bottom:10px;``` le pones ```top:10px;``` y al ```.timeline``` le añades la propiedad ```top:120px;``` (La cantidad de pixeles que ocupa las flechas). Si tienes una posición absoluta si le pones ````bottom``` estará abajo, si le pones ```top``` estará arriba

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, si funciono tal y como me lo indicas, pero no me deja colocar tu respuesta como favorito o la mejor.